# Unexpected collection returned in Symfony

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I've created an Customer entity with a ManyToOne relation to Partner. The Partner has a inverse OneToMany relation to Customer.

I'm calling `$partner->getCustomers()` and I do have a result that is ok, though I can't explain something. First, here is the query :

```
public function getCustomersByPartner(SerializerInterface $serializer, $id)
{
    /* @var $partner Partner */
    $partner = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Partner::class)->find($id);
    $customers = $serializer->serialize($partner->getCustomers(), 'json');

    $response = new Response($customers);
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    return $response;
}
```

And here is the full result (when calling host/partner/3 route where 3 is the partner id) :

```
[
    {
        "id": 4,
        "url": "www.test.com",
        "subscription_status": "active",
        "first_payment": "2019-02-22T09:55:47+00:00",
        "created_at": "2019-02-22T09:55:47+00:00",
        "updated_at": "2019-02-22T09:55:47+00:00",
        "partner": {
            "id": 3,
            "firstname": "Partner3",
            "lastname": "Partner3",
            "authenticated": 1,
            "created_at": "2019-02-22T10:05:04+00:00",
            "updated_at": "2019-02-22T10:05:04+00:00",
            "customers": [
                {
                    "id": 9,
                    "url": "www.blabla.com",
                    "subscription_status": "active",
                    "first_payment": "2019-02-22T13:23:43+00:00",
                    "created_at": "2019-02-22T13:23:43+00:00",
                    "updated_at": "2019-02-22T13:23:43+00:00"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 9,
        "url": "www.blabla.com",
        "subscription_status": "active",
        "first_payment": "2019-02-22T13:23:43+00:00",
        "created_at": "2019-02-22T13:23:43+00:00",
        "updated_at": "2019-02-22T13:23:43+00:00",
        "partner": {
            "id": 3,
            "firstname": "Partner3",
            "lastname": "Partner3",
            "authenticated": 1,
            "created_at": "2019-02-22T10:05:04+00:00",
            "updated_at": "2019-02-22T10:05:04+00:00",
            "customers": [
                {
                    "id": 4,
                    "url": "www.test.com",
                    "subscription_status": "active",
                    "first_payment": "2019-02-22T09:55:47+00:00",
                    "created_at": "2019-02-22T09:55:47+00:00",
                    "updated_at": "2019-02-22T09:55:47+00:00"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

I do have all customers that belong to the Partner id **3**, but I was expecting my `customers` array (in both "partner" objects) to contain every customer attached to that Partner (so, customer 4 and customer 9 in this case).

I can't really put words on it, I hope you understand what I mean.
Thats what I would have expected :

```
"customers": [
                {
                    "id": 9,
                    "url": "www.blabla.com",
                    "subscription_status": "active",
                    "first_payment": "2019-02-22T13:23:43+00:00",
                    "created_at": "2019-02-22T13:23:43+00:00",
                    "updated_at": "2019-02-22T13:23:43+00:00"
                },
                {
                    "id": 4,
                    "url": "www.test.com",
                    "subscription_status": "active",
                    "first_payment": "2019-02-22T09:55:47+00:00",
                    "created_at": "2019-02-22T09:55:47+00:00",
                    "updated_at": "2019-02-22T09:55:47+00:00"
                }
            ]
```

Is it because Symfony is returing the first customer first, then shows what's remaining ? Is that a Doctrine specific behaviour ?

Whats funny is that if I do the opposite, and go to see what customer belong to which partner, I do have that result returned :
(calling host/customer/4 route where 4 is the customer id)

```
{
    "id": 3,
    "firstname": "Partner3",
    "lastname": "Partner3",
    "authenticated": 1,
    "created_at": "2019-02-22T10:05:04+00:00",
    "updated_at": "2019-02-22T10:05:04+00:00",
    "customers": [
        {
            "id": 4,
            "url": "www.test.com",
            "subscription_status": "active",
            "first_payment": "2019-02-22T09:55:47+00:00",
            "created_at": "2019-02-22T09:55:47+00:00",
            "updated_at": "2019-02-22T09:55:47+00:00"
        },
        {
            "id": 9,
            "url": "www.blabla.com",
            "subscription_status": "active",
            "first_payment": "2019-02-22T13:23:43+00:00",
            "created_at": "2019-02-22T13:23:43+00:00",
            "updated_at": "2019-02-22T13:23:43+00:00"
        },
        {
            "id": 10,
            "url": "www.blabla.com",
            "subscription_status": "active",
            "first_payment": "2019-02-22T13:53:02+00:00",
            "created_at": "2019-02-22T13:53:02+00:00",
            "updated_at": "2019-02-22T13:53:02+00:00"
        }
    ]
}
```

And thats the function :

```
/**
 * @Route("/customer/{id}", name="customer_detail")
 * @param SerializerInterface $serializer Serializer service
 * @param Integer $id Id of customer
 * @return Response Return name of the partner
 */
public function getPartnerByCustomer(SerializerInterface $serializer, $id)
{
    /* @var $customer Customer */
    $customer = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Customer::class)->find($id);
    $partner = $serializer->serialize($customer->getPartner(), 'json');

    $response = new Response($partner);
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    return $response;
}
```

Which is exactly what I would have expected for the first request. Thank you for your time.

Comment: One of possible reasons would be a fact that you're using serializer to render response in json. Since `customers` property within `Parner` obviously contains root customer itself - you're facing circular reference and handling of such situation depends on serializer. I would recommend you to look at resulted structure through debugger or via `var_dump()`. Please also notice that depending on your fetching strategy you may not get results from collection in a case of lazy loading

Comment: @Flying Thank you for your reply. If I try to var dump the whole thing I get a sh*tload of data, I just can't do it. I will try via debugger, or via anotehr serializer maybe. Can you explain why I may not get results from collection in case of lazy loading ? thanks again

Comment: In a case of lazy loading actual collection contents are loaded at a time of first attempt to access these contents. Serializers (depending on their configuration) may access object contents via reflection instead of methods and in a case of reflection they will not trigger collection contents loading

Comment: Oh ok, that makes sense. But how could I retrieve data without using a serializer ? Im a bit lost here :)

Comment: You can manage the objects using Groups annotation. So you set the same group to all properties that you want to return and then, serialize the object indicating the group:

$this->serializer->serialize($customer->getPartner(), 'json', array('groups' => array('customers-data')));

Comment: thanks @AythaNzt, I went to see about this on the doc, and found out that solution, will try :) Im using jms serializert so I just need to adapt a bit